# Xen Cloud Platform and the command line

Tags: xen

Is it possible to manage a small [XCP](http://xen.org/products/cloudxen.html) installation (less than 10 boxes) via the command line (and the xe command) or is using [cloudstack](http://cloudstack.org/) or something similar almost mandatory?

Comment: With small amount like 10 boxes almost everything should be easily scriptable. Tell us more about your management requirements.

Comment: I have no clear management requirements yet, other than being able to do stuff remotely and ssh is fine. Also it is not going to be a setup where VMs come and go daily, rather instead of replacing old machinery with new, use a VM where possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rest of the team decided that we should use cloudstack anyway ...